# How can I store a data contains "." inside firestore inside a map field in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I add an email address to the map field vote data, Due to "." inside email address, it is creating a sub map with email.

How can I overcome this??

//Code Below

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('polls')
        .doc(pollId)
        .update({"voteData.$currentUser": option});
```

Here currentUser = "vilakshan2914@gmail.com"

[image]

I tried this code too

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('polls')
        .doc(pollId)
        .update({"voteData.${currentUser.replaceAll(".", "\\.")}": option});
```

but output is

[image]

Comment: Consider removing your personal GMail account from your question by editing the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `.`

Try this,

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('polls')
        .doc(pollId)
        .update({"voteData.${currentUser.replaceAll(".","\\.")}": option});
```

Comment: not Working as expected , I also updated the question

Comment: Do you really want the `.` in the mail there?

Comment: Anyway thanks I Used "_" instead of ".